# Stop Parallel.For on all threads when the limit has been reached?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get all the images a user has posted on their profile. I do this using an API, the api shows a maximum of 50 of the latest posts the user has posted. To get more than 50 you need to call to a second page, each page has 50 so if you want the last 200, run 4 pages.

I started using parallel for this otherwise it would of taken ages. The question I'm asking is, is there a way to totally stop every interation of the parallel for once its reached a stage where there aren't any more images to collect?

As you can see from below, I have a todo. Now I could just break out of it, but some interations go further than they need to, a lot actually. Is there a way to stop all interations as soon as any parallel part has hit the limit where there are no more images to collect?

```
public List<TumblrFile> GetImagesForAddress(string pageAddress, string saveLocation)
{
    var imageUrls = new List<TumblrFile>();

    Parallel.For(0, _pageCount,
    index => {
        var document = XDocument.Load(GetApiLink(pageAddress, index * 50, true));
        var newImages = XmlUtilities.ExtractImagesFromDocument(document, saveLocation);

        if (newImages.Count < 1)
        {
            // TODO: Stop this loop
        }

        foreach (var newImage in newImages)
        {
            if (imageUrls.All(x => x.Address != newImage.Address))
            {
                imageUrls.Add(newImage);
            }
        }
    });

    return imageUrls;
}
```

Comment: Couple of comments: (i) many servers will limit parallel connections; asking for them all at once unless you own the server is (a) obnoxious and (b) likely to fail.  (ii) `List` isn't thread-safe, you can't call `Add` like this on it and expect it to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

there is an overload to parallel for that looks like this

```
Parallel.For(0, pageCount, (index, loopState) =>
```

use that, and when you want to break say
    loopState.Stop();

Comment: You need to use `loopState.Break()` not `.Stop()` and you need to test loopstate before launching a web request, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your _pagecount is 4 but the resource only have 60 images. Your code will create 4 tasks and executed by the TaskScheduler accordingly. You can assume it's parallel.

- Task 1: Get 0 to 49
- Task 2: Get 50 to 59
- Task 3: Get nothing
- Task 4: Get nothing

What you expect is when Task 3 get nothing, then Task 4 should be aborted while Task 1 and 2 should continue until the end.

If my understanding is valid, `Parallel.For(0, _pageCount, (index, loopstate) =>` won't help because it will stop the individual task and does not care the rest.

To achieve what you expect, there could be 2 options:

Option 1: Assume you can know the number of total images.
Then all you need to do is to dynamically calculate the _pageCount.

Option 2: Assume you do not know the number of total images.
You can have one while loop like this:

```
        while (true)
        {
            var result = ParallelGetImage(yourLevelOfParallelism);
            if (result == null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using `Parallel.For` for this. Microsoft has an excellent library called the "Reactive Framework" (or Rx.NET) that does this kind of work superbly.

Here's what you need in your `GetImagesForAddress` method.

```
    // Effectively infinite pages of images query
    IObservable<List<TumblrFile>> observableOfListsOfImages=
        from index in Observable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
        from document in Observable.Start(() => XDocument.Load(GetApiLink(pageAddress, index * 50, true)))
        from images in Observable.Start(() => XmlUtilities.ExtractImagesFromDocument(document, saveLocation))
        select images;

    // Stop query when empty list returned
    // and wait for results
    TumblrFile[] arrayOfImages =
        observableOfListsOfImages
            .TakeWhile(x => x.Any())
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .ToArray()
            .Wait();

    // Remove any duplicates based on `.Address` property
    List<TumblrFile> listOfImages =
        arrayOfImages
            .GroupBy(x => x.Address)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))
            .ToList();

    return listOfImages;
```

That's the entire body of your method.

It does all of the threading and takes care of all of the concurrency for you.

You just need to add "System.Reactive" as a NuGet package and then add the `System.Reactive.Linq` namespace to your code.

There's no need to limit by `_pageCount` either (but you could by swapping out the `int.MaxValue`).

Finally, there's an even better possibility. You could return an `IObservable<TumblrFile>` instead of `List<TumblrFile>` to be able to get the files as soon as they are produced. Your code would look like this:

```
public IObservable<TumblrFile> GetImagesForAddress2(string pageAddress, string saveLocation)
{
    // Effectively infinite pages of images query
    IObservable<List<TumblrFile>> observableOfListsOfImages=
        from index in Observable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
        from document in Observable.Start(() => XDocument.Load(GetApiLink(pageAddress, index * 50, true)))
        from images in Observable.Start(() => XmlUtilities.ExtractImagesFromDocument(document, saveLocation))
        select images;

    // Stop query when empty list returned
    // and remove duplicates by `.Address`
    return
        observableOfListsOfImages
            .TakeWhile(x => x.Any())
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Address)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Take(1));
}
```

You just need to call `.Subscribe(image => /* code here to process each image */);` to process the results.

Answer (score -1):

A clean way to do this would be to update a shared variable once the limit has been found and then at the start of each call, check see if the limit has been found and if the index is beyond the limit, do nothing.

You need to do it this way because you cannot guarantee the order in which your parallel executions will happen and you don't want to stop lower indexes that might not have started.

One thing to be careful of is that you may need to update the shared variable more than once if a lower limit is found in a later execution. You can either get clever and use `Interlocked.CompareAndExchange` to do this, or, start simple and use a `lock` statement around all access to this shared 'end value'.

---

Alternatively, you can use loop state as someone else suggested (now deleted) but you need to call `Break()` not `Stop()` so that the other threads with an earlier index keep running and you need to check for `loopState.IsStopped` before each call to fetch the web page.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721(v=vs.110).aspx

---

And in either case you should set the maximum degrees of parallelism on the `Parallel.For` to limit how many api calls it is making simultaneously.